# cpp inheritance (access parent data member value by child)

Tags: c++, inheritance, parent-child, access-specifier

Is there a way to access data member values of the Parent by Child? Below example:

.h file:

```
#ifndef PRAC_H
#define PRAC_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ToolFrame {
    public:
        string  mManuID;
        void    setManuID(string manu_id) { mManuID = manu_id; }
        string  getManuID() { return mManuID; }
};

class Hammer : public ToolFrame {
    int     mDurability;
    public:
        void    setDurability(int durability) { mDurability = durability; }
        int     getDurability() { return mDurability; }
};
```

.cpp file:

```
#include "prac.h" 

int main() {
    ToolFrame xz00;
    Hammer bonker100;

    xz00.setManuID("00a1d");
    bonker100.setDurability(50);
    cout << bonker100.getDurability() << endl;
    cout << bonker100.getManuID() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:
50

output should be:
50
00a1d

issue:
I understood "cout << bonker100.getManuID() << endl;" should access Parent's data member value (mManuID), as the member is not set to private. However, output is not the set value "00a1d".

question:
cant children access parent's public value in this manner?

Tried different access specifiers, by moving Parent's data members from private to public. Set link between child and parent to public.

Comment: You did not set the manuID of bonker100 (instance of Hammer) but of xz00 (instance of baseclass). You should set "00a1d" for bonker100 to get your desired output

Comment: Yes. If I had 100 hammer objects, which all have the same base ToolFrame (00a1d), it would be efficient to inherit this value for all the children, only by setting the value for the Parent. I thought this is one of the benefits of inheritance. I suppose I have misunderstood?

Comment: `xz00` and `bonker100` are different instances...

Comment: _"output should be: 50 00a1d"_. Why do you think that?  You have two distinct and separate variables, and you are only printing the data in one of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Child classes inherit properties and members, not values. Hammer instance `bonker100` has inherited member `mManuID` and public (also protected, but there are none in this case) methods of a `ToolFrame`, but it has its member default-constructed. `ToolFrame` and `Hammer` objects are *not the same* - they are different pieces of data and don't share their values.

Comment: Yes. Thanks! I arrived to what I aimed for by setting values for the Parent in .h file, instead of via creating a new instance of ToolFrame, and using setters for that instance. By this way, Hammer objects inherited the Parent values.